# Windows Forms Combobox mouseover events

Tags: .net, combobox, mouseevent

I'm working with a .net application and the mouseover/hover events don't appear to be triggering unless I hover over the button that opens the dropdown box; no amount of hovering over the text entry position reliably triggers the event. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ComboBox.MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx) event rather. You can adjust the logic there in..